# Optimistic Locking in Spring Data JDBC

Tags: spring-data, optimistic-locking, spring-data-jdbc

I noticed that Spring Data JDBC doesn't seem to implemented Optimistic Locking (something like a JPA's @Version annotation).

I was thinking on creating a `@Modifying` query which considers the version field and returns `boolean` to check manually if the update was successful or not. But I'm afraid this approach is limited to *simple* entities, not aggregates implying multiple tables.

What's the best way to implement optimistic locking for aggregates?

Comment: Version 2.0 of Spring Data JDBC will contain support for Optimistic Locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your situation. If you just have 7 aggregates of which 5 are single entity aggregates go for the `@Modifying` solution for the single aggregates and write custom methods for the other 2.

If you have more aggregates consisting of more then one class consider properly implementing it and submitting a PR. The issue is already there: https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJDBC/issues/DATAJDBC-219

The main code changes will be in [SqlGenerator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/SqlGenerator.java) which would need to add a where clause for aggregate roots if they have a version attribute.

If you are interested in doing a PR and need more assistance, please leave comment on the issue.